# TypeError: 'map' object is not subscriptable in python 3.8

Tags: python

I have a problem while running this :

```
file_Cond = open(filename2)
header_line = next(file_Cond)
tmp = map(int, header_line[8:].strip().split())
Nelements = tmp[0]
header_line = next(file_Cond)
tmp = map(int, header_line[8:].strip().split() )
Nnodes = tmp[0]
next(file_Cond)`
```

The line `Nelements = tmp[0]` raises the following error :

```
TypeError: 'map' object is not subscriptable
```

Do you have an idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: It would help if you disclosed what you are trying to do: why not just `n_elements = int(header_line[8:].strip().split()[0])`? Don't write, never publish uncommented/undocumented code.

Answer (score 1):

In python 3.8, `map` function returns a map object and not a list. You can convert it to a list by passing it to `list(..)`.

`tmp = list(map(int, header_line[8:].strip().split()))`